# How to prevent hamburger menu replace over back button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I've been using:

**react-native-router-flux** v4.0.6

**react** v16.6.3

**react-native** v0.57.8

I have a simple question.
I have two component: **Listing.js** and **Detail.js**

And I have a drawer menu. The problem is that when user click the detail button in the Listing, next page the hamburger menu icon still exist.

But I want to change the hamburger menu to back button.

```js
<Router sceneStyle={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
    <Scene 
        contentComponent={SideMenu} 
        drawerWidth={280} 
        drawerPosition={'left'} 
        drawerImage={require('./hamburger.png')} 
        initial 
        drawer
    >
        <Scene key='main'>
            <Scene key='list' component={Listing} title='Albüm APP' initial />
            <Scene key='detail' component={Detail} title='Albüm Detay' />
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

**Here the problem:**

[image]

[image]

**Here I want to do:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you can override the default navbar with a custom navbar

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import mainScreen from './components/mainScreen';
import challengeScreen from './components/challengeScreen';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
<Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="homeScreen" component={mainScreen} hideNavBar={1} />
    <Scene
     key="screen2" component={challengeScreen} navTransparent={1}
     navBar={NavBar}
       />
</Scene>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default RouterComponent;
```

// NavBar.js

```
import {
 View, Image, StatusBar, TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar />
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Actions.homeScreen()}>
      <Image
    source={require('./Images/back-arrow.png')}
    style={styles.backarrowStyle} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      <Image
  source={require('./Images/help.png')}
  style={styles.helpStyle} />


  <Image
source={require('./Images/setting.png')}
style={styles.settingStyle} />
    </View>
</View>
    );
  }

}
const styles = {
  backgroundStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  backarrowStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    left: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  helpStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      left: 220,
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      position: 'relative'

  },
  settingStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  position: 'relative',
  left: 210
  }
};


export default NavBar;
```

Comment: the hamburger menu appears in the drawer or in the Detail component?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help Nunchucks.
Hamburger menu appears in the Detail component.

Comment: Please post more code :) I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: I added images. You can look.

Comment: I only see drawerImage={require('./hamburger.png')} . Where is the code where you are trying to render ./backArrow.png ?

Comment: I use react-native-router-flux. It is automatically generated/replaced when screen change. For instance, when click detail button in the listing page, it shows up on the detail screen. I don't place it, react-native-router-flux does.

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding of react-native-router-flux. After reading some documentation, it looks like you can do the above and override the hamburger navbar with a custom navbar for each scene like ` <Scene
     key="screen2" component={challengeScreen} navTransparent={1}
     navBar={NavBar}
       />` Please give my updated answer a try

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply adding the prop `back` to your `detail` scene ?

```
<Scene 
  key='detail' 
  component={Detail} 
  title='Albüm Detay' 
  back
/>
```

From the docs about `back` prop

> If it is true back button is displayed instead of left/drawer button defined by upper container.